# File::Compare's compare always returns -1

Tags: perl

Background: I have no experience with Perl and have only started today, I am trying to compare two files line-by-line, find the lines that are different and record which ones they were in a separate document. I am yet to get that far, as I am adding in the functionality one step at a time.

Error: I am doing the compare on the two file handles and I am getting -1, which is an error, according to the File::Compare documentation. However, I cannot see where the error is occurring.

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Compare;

my $filename1 = 'test1.txt';
my $filename2 = 'test2.txt';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename1)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename1' $!";
open(my $fr, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename2)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename2' $!";

while () {
  my $row1 = <$fh>;
  my $row2 = <$fr>;
  my $row1Num;
  my $row2Num;
  if ($row1 && $row2) {
    chomp $row1;
    chomp $row2;
    $row1Num = substr($row1, 0, index($row1, ','));
    $row2Num = substr($row2, 0, index($row2, ','));
    while ($row1Num != $row2Num) {
      if (!$row1 || !$row2) {
        last;
      }
      if ($row1Num < $row2Num) {
        #! Add row1Num to the list
        print "$row1\n";
        $row1 = <$fh>;
        if (!$row1) {
          last;
        }
        chomp $row1;
        $row1Num = substr($row1, 0, index($row1Num, ','));
      } else {
        #! Add row2Num to the list
        print "$row2\n";
        $row2 = <$fr>;
        if (!$row2){
          last;
        }
        chomp $row2;
        $row2Num = substr($row2, 0, index($row2Num, ','));
      }
    }
  }
  if ($row1 && $row2)
  {
    if (compare($row1,$row2) != 0)
    {
      #! Add row1Num to the list
      my $compare = compare($row1,$row2);
      my $compare2 = compare($row2,$row1);
      print "Compare($row1,$row2) == $compare\n";
      print "Compare($row2,$row1) == $compare2\n";
    }
  } elsif (!$row1 && $row2) {
    #! Add row2Num to the list
    chomp $row2;
    print "$row2\n";
  } elsif ($row1 && !$row2) {
    #! Add row1Num to the list
    chomp $row1;
    print "$row1\n";
  } else {
    last;
  }
}
print "done\n";
```

Output:

```
Compare(1,a,1,1) == -1
Compare(1,1,1,a) == -1
Compare(2,b,2,2) == -1
Compare(2,2,2,b) == -1
Compare(3,3,3,3) == -1
Compare(3,3,3,3) == -1
4,d
5,5
done
```

test1.txt:

```
1,a
2,b
3,3
4,d
```

test2.txt:

```
1,1
2,2
3,3
5,5
```

If anyone can spot where I am being an idiot, I would be very thankful.

Comment: Try typing `perldoc -q intersection` at your command line to get some idea about how to get it done.

Comment: File::Compare's `compare` expects the names of files to compare as arguments. It looks like you simply want the `eq` operator.

Answer (score 0):

ikegami noted the error in your code regarding [File::Compare](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Compare). Here is a possible solution that makes use of a hash, `%count`.

It records how many times a line from either file is found. If the count == 1, then that line has only been seen once in both of the files - I think that is the result you want.

Instead of explicitly opening each file, I supplied the filenames on the command line. This allows the `while <>`syntax to read both files. The command line would look like:

`perl program_name.pl test1.txt test2.txt`

(Also note that I used a cache for the sort subroutine which will increase the speed of your program if there are a large, (1000+), number of differences to be sorted. The cache isn't necessary but is useful if you have a large amount of items to sort)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %count;
$count{$_}++ while <>;

print sort by_row_num grep $count{$_} == 1, keys %count;

my %cache;
sub by_row_num {
    ($cache{$a} //= substr($a, 0, index($a, ',')))
                    <=>
    ($cache{$b} //= substr($b, 0, index($b, ',')))
}
```

The output from your sample data is:

```
1,a
1,1
2,2
2,b
4,d
5,5
```